# Saving project (build) settings in Eclipse CDT

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

Is there an option somewhere in CDT (Juno) where I can set customized "Release" configurations for my projects?

All I want to do for now is to be able to create a new C++ project and have by default the `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu11`options for the compilers and `-s` for the linker, and maybe a few other optimization flags. It's not a big hassle to do it every time for every new program, but I was just wondering, since I've been creating a lot of small programs to get to know C++ better.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of any such "built-in" mechanism. Of course, you can extend the C++ new-project wizard to do whatever you want, but that requires a bit of work.

Comment: @JesperE Hm, by a bit of work do you mean clicking a lot of check boxes or performing actual black magic? I've looked there for a while, and I couldn't find that kind of settings for the tool chain. I really need to learn how to deal with environments that are not called Visual Studio...

Comment: By "a bit of work" I mean writing real Java code. No black magic, although if you have never written Eclipse plugins, then you have a bit of learning curve up ahead. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to change the default template.
When you create a new simple project, based on a templated with 10 changes, you have to undo many of the 10 amendments. Now it is possible to miss one or more important settings.

Probably this will be the basis for new questions on stackoverflow. Can not build a new project, created by the c++ Hello world sample.

it gets boring quickly, to change the default project for each project. So it makes sense to create a template project, for example, the Hello World program for each architecture / toolchain that you work with and make a copy for each new project. Copying projects is simple.

Copy and paste the whole project name it to **template-c++11-gnu11** and make all the changes you want. From now on only **copy and paste and rename it to a real project name**.

Thus, the example templates will keep it that way for which they are intended.

Comment: Ohhh... Thanks. That will do nicely.